# Getting twitter user's actual name, not screen_name

Tags: twitter

Using Twitter's API, I am able to get the list of tweets and so forth in the following format:

> @Beyonce | I released a new music video today, check it out!

I am using `"@{$status->user->screen_name}` and that works fine, however I wanted to get the **name** of the account, ie in this case it would be **Beyoncé Knowles**.

I can't find anything that specifies in the documentation which parameter gets the name so I could use the following format:

> Beyoncé Knowles @Beyonce | I released a new music video today, check it out!

Answer (score -1):

Whoops, never mind! Just found it ;)

Use `{$status->user->name}`